# Generating set without elements of order 2

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, finitely-generated, cayley-graphs

I proved that every group acts freely by left translation on its Cayley graph if and only if the generating set $S$ of the group $G$ has no elements of order $2$.

Is it true that every finitely generated nontrivial group has a finite generating set without elements of order 2? If not, please give me a counterexample.

Comment: Am I missing something? What about $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I don't follow. Freeness has nothing to do with the edges; every group $G$ acts freely on itself, so every group $G$ acts freely on the vertices of the Cayley graph with respect to any generating set.

Comment: @Qiaochu: he means, acts freely on the 1-skeleton. To avoid the issue, one solution is to consider the oriented Cayley graph. So a generator of order two gives rise to a pair of opposite edges and the action is always free.